# Excel: Find max corresponding value of multiple instances

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a formula to solve this problem in excel:

Sheet 1 – write a number in col.

1. find all instances of that number in sheet 2, col. A, and the corresponding values in sheet 2 col.
2. Return the highs corresponding value in sheet 1 col B.

I.e. If I write 100 in cell A3 (sheet 1) the formula returns 30 in cell B3 ((sheet 1).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you have Office 365 Excel use this:

```
=MAXIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A,A3)
```

If you do not have Office 365 but later then 2010:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet2!B1:B100/(Sheet2!A1:A100=A3),1)
```

If you are using 2007 or later then you will need to use this array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet2!A1:A100=A3,Sheet2!B1:B100))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-
Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: This Works. Cheers!

Comment: @Eddy please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.